# typeahead on input dynamically added by directive

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have a directive that dynamically adds an input in response to clicks on the container.  I would like to be able to put a typeahead on the directive element that gets applied to the dynamic input.  I have set up this plunk to demonstrate.

http://plnkr.co/edit/199KeGRAd32ZeOIjTKe6?p=preview

In my app, the typeahead source is an http call.  I put some console logs in the function that makes the http call and do see results coming back, so I know the typeahead is firing, but as you can see in the plunk, the typeahead drop down never appears.  What am I doing wrong?

**note**
cross [posted](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!category-topic/angular-ui/bootstrap/tSzt5W3A5tM) on angularui's google group

Comment: I think you need to fix your plnkr... `Uncaught Error: No module: ui.bootstrap`

Comment: argh...plunker dropped some files...ill add them back

Answer (score 2):

I had a look at your code, but I could not make it work. Instead maybe you could use a similar feature of AngularUI. They have directive based on the Select2 jQuery plugin.

Have a look at: http://angular-ui.github.io/#/directives-select2

And read the Select2 documentation in order to use multi-values (there is a nice demo):
http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/#multi

I hope it can help you.

Comment: We are using select2 elsewhere, I will have to see if it can handle all our needs for this (including styling without editing the js).

Answer (score 1):

Is there some reason you need the complexity of `$compile`?  The typeahead directive doesn't seem to let you pass it through very easily, but if you provide use a more generic data source, you can do it like this:

http://plnkr.co/edit/SFhS7kbmI1c6pEyRS18v?p=preview

HTML:

```
<test test-model="test" test-typeahead-data-source="getData()"></test>
```

JavaScript:

```
app.directive("test", function($rootScope, $compile) {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      testModel: '=',
      testTypeaheadDataSource: '='
    },
    template: '<input type="text" ng-model="testModel" typeahead="test as test.name for test in testTypeaheadDataSource" />'
  }
});
```

Comment: how do I attache the keyup event handler to that?